# combine p4 describe and p4 changes commands to get the result needed

Tags: windows, perforce

The thing is that 
with `p4 changes` command you can specify time range for all of the changelists that were submitted during that period of time
for example

```
p4 changes -l //depot/main/Project/src/...@2013/02/20,@now"
```

will give you detailed information about each changelist submitted, but will not give you file names that were included to this changelists.

And the

```
p4 describe 6254561
```

command will give you all the information about 6254561 changelist including files that were affected, but you can't specify range of time for all the changelists.

is there chance to combine those commands somehow? 
or maybe there is command that does what I need but I just don't know about it?
I simply need to get all the description about each changelist, files affected in this changelist, and project path and range of time.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should point you in the right direction:

```
for /f "tokens=2" %x in ('p4 changes //depot/main/Project/src/...@2013/02/20^,@now') do @(p4 describe -s %x & echo --------)
```

Notice the escaped `,` in there.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Mac or Linux, you can pipe the two commands together to get the output you need:

```
p4 changes -l //depot/main/Project/src/...@2013/02/20,@now" | cut -d " " -f 2 | xargs p4 describe
```

Comment: You could use CygWin (a UNIX shell for Windows) to run the above command.  There might be a Windows-native way to chain the commands together, but I'm afraid I don't know Windows well enough to offer any answers.

Comment: You can do the same thing on Windows; you just need Windows versions of `cut` and `xargs`.  Both are available through unxutils.sourceforge.net.

Answer (score 0):

You should pick a scripting language with which you're comfortable: Perl, Python, Ruby, etc. All of these scripting languages have full-featured Perforce libraries, and come with lots of examples of how to write simple scripts like these.

Spending a few minutes up front to get comfortable with the scripting language of your choice, and with how how it interacts with Perforce, will result in a much better tool development experience down the line, when you are ready to write more complex and detailed scripts for your work needs.

Look here to get started: http://www.perforce.com/product/components/apis